# Transfer downloaded files whonix workstation to my usb drive working on virtualbox?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, debian, file-transfer

I have whonix workstation installed on virtualbox running on windows 10 host. I have downloaded some files inside whonix workstation to my pendrive or external hardrive. But it is not recognizing my drive. I have also enabled "mount my removable device when inserted" in the settings of whonix workstation. I know this is for security purpose but I installed whonix for temporary works.And now I need those files out.Is there a way? how to access pendrive on whonix running inside oracle virtualbox? Can I access those files on my host windows 10? Or by using some apps like airdroid or some dlna server? I just need a full proof solution .

Comment: Who is "it" in "it is not recognizing…"? I mean, you state, "I have downloaded ... in(side) whonix workstation to my pendrive" which meant you _have succeeded_ in downloading the files, then you state that some "it" failed to not recoginze the drive. So what is that "it", and which drive it failed to recognize? I think it would be better to stop thinking about pendrives and instead state the root problem. You have "whonix" running in a Virtualbox running on Windows 10; what do you wish to do with the files in this setup?

Comment: it is "whonix workstation" and I want to save those files back in my pendrive for future use .Whonix workstation is not recognizing external drive or usb sticks I am inserting to backup all the downloaded files.When I insert the external drive ,it got recogized by my host machine"win 10" but not by "whonix workstation"

Comment: Have you checked [the guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtualbox+pass-through+USB+stick+from+host+to+guest)? None of them works, right?

Comment: I have not seen the guides but using shared folders in virtual box ,I have managed to share files in between host machine and guest machine.Thanks D:

Comment: Basically that's the "go to" method for such deployments, I thought you needed USB stick for some particular reason, but OK ;-)